# If eigenvectors of different eigenvalues are orthogonal, then is the matrix normal?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It is axiomatic that eigenvectors of normal matrices are orthogonal. Then how about the converse? Is it still true?

Comment: False, but it might be interesting to explore what additional conditions make it true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample: the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ meets your criteria, but isn’t even diagonalizable.